# Why is add_action() not correctly executed in a conditional statement?

Tags: wordpress, hook

In `functions.php`, I want to attach a function to a hook only for the front page:

```
function dequeue_iw_theme_styles() {
  wp_dequeue_style('iw');
}
if (is_page('new-front-page')) {
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_iw_theme_styles', 100);  
}
```

This code doesn't work though. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it the other way around:

```
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_iw_theme_styles', 100);

    function dequeue_iw_theme_styles() {
        if (is_page('new-front-page')) {
            wp_dequeue_style('iw');
        }            
    }
```

I believe the problem is that by conditionally adding the action, you're already too late to tell if its a certain template. This way, you are adding the action no matter what, and only executing the code if the template matches.

Comment: +1. Yes, you should wrap the condition around the function contents as it achieves the same thing but will allow the hook to callback the function regardless of any conditions placed upon the hook.

Comment: what if it was a filter passing a value to edit?